# Not able to get navigation drawer item id to open an activity

Tags: android

I am trying to get my app to work to open my activity to click on the navigation drawer but I am not able to get the menu id.

**.java**

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

         switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.home_id:
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tarun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Intent home_Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(home_Intent);
                  break;

             return true;
         }
     });
```

This is my menu item xml  here is also provide the id and the name which will show me in navigation view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_id"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"/>    
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you provide the drawer's menu xml code as well?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_id"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        />   </group>


</menu>

Comment: i have added my menu xml code

Comment: Seems strange. Based on the provided code, it should work. Can you please add a line to log into LogCat what's the menuItem.getItemId() you get?

Comment: Also check if you are inflating the correct menu.xml for that.

Comment: menuitem.getitemId() it prints nothing in log

Comment: where  i want to inflatte the menu in xml or code

Comment: it should print something. if it is firing the event listed by your listener, then there should be a clicked item. to see which menu you are inflating, check your layout's xml code

Comment: please tell to me first where i want to inflate menu in xml or activity

Comment: if you see the menu in the app, you already are inflating something. can you please add the layout's xml code here?